# Entity Framework fails if executed from pendrive or server

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first, app-config

My app was created using .Net 4.0 Client Profile, WPF, EF 6.0, Code-First, 2 dataproviders (SQL Server CE and MySQL).

If I copy the debug/release folder to a **local file path**, it works fine.

But if a copy this folder to a **pendrive** or put in a **server folder**.
The first time I need to create a `DbContext` or call a database initializer, its fails with the following error (`J:` is my pendrive):

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception
>   An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for Entity Framework: Request failed.(**J:**\USERS\George\Release\app.Config line 6)
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Request failed. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
>
>   at System.Void System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1[DG.Apps.JLM.Questoes.Domain.Contexts.QuestoesContext]..ctor()
>   at System.Void DG.Apps.JLM.Questoes.Presentation.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) in j:\USERS\George\Release\Common\Common\Apps\JLM\DG.Apps.JLM.Questoes\DG.Apps.JLM.Questoes.Presentation\App.xaml.cs:line 30
>   at Object System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object unused)
>   at Object System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, System.Object args, System.Int32 numArgs)
>   at Object MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object source, System.Delegate method, System.Object args, System.Int32 numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler)
>   at System.Void System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>   at static System.Void System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object state)
>   at static System.Void System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object userData)
>   at static System.Void System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
>   at static System.Void System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
>   at static System.Void System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
>   at Object System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>   at System.Void System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>   at IntPtr System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Int32 msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, System.Boolean handled)
>   at IntPtr MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Int32 msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, System.Boolean handled)
>   at Object MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object o)
>   at Object System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, System.Object args, System.Int32 numArgs)
>   at Object MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object source, System.Delegate method, System.Object args, System.Int32 numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler)
>   at Object System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, System.Object args, System.Int32 numArgs)
>   at IntPtr MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Int32 msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)
>   at System.Void System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at static System.Void System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at static System.Void System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
>   at Object System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object ignore)
>   at Int32 System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)
>   at Int32 System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)
>   at Int32 System.Windows.Application.Run()
>   at static System.Void DG.Apps.JLM.Questoes.Presentation.App.Main()

Just like the one described in this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/806804ba-b9c6-4639-9119-a4909f9a6d25/entity-framework-type-initializer-app-config?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Here is my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QuestoesContextSqlServerCE" connectionString="Data Source=Questoes.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0" />
    <add name="QuestoesContextMySQL" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=questoes" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

and here is my wpf app `OnStartup`, the app crash when calling `SetInitializer`

```
namespace DG.Apps.JLM.Questoes.Presentation
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<QuestoesContext>());
```

As I said at the beginning, the app runs fine if the folder is in a local file path, only fails if executed in a server folder or a pendrive folder

Comment: Did you figure anything out regarding this? I have the same issue it seems.

Comment: @PeterHansen No, but i came with a alternative solution, using clickonce. The pendrive or server has the clickonce application files. When the user execute from the pendrive, the clickonce copies the files to another location in the computer and executes from there, so the error doesn't occur.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. My program was created using WPF (targeting the .NET Framework 4), Visual Studio 2013 and my computer has .NET 4.5.2 on it. I could run the program perfectly fine and other machines that also had .NET 4.5.2 on it could run it perfectly fine but when I put it on another machine which had only .NET 4.0 on it, that is when I got the error you described. What I guess I am saying is that I think it has something to do with how the 4.5.2 framework emulates the 4.0 framework.

Anyways, I fixed the problem by simply removing the entire entityFramework section of the app config.

```
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
   <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

I just took the above part out of my code and left literally everything else--in the app config and in all other files--alone.

Make sure to leave your

```
<connectionStrings>
   ...
</connectionStrings>
```

section there.

I do realize you have more things in your entityFramework section than I do so I hope my solution will actually solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me too! Thank you!But.. do you know exxacly why?

Comment: I never did figure out exactly why it fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: I'd really love to know how can such an edit solve the issue. It worked for me too, but I don't get it.